# Setting active mode for FTP in ATOM

Tags: windows, ftp, atom-editor

Do you know [ATOM](https://atom.io/)? It's developed by the GitHub's community:

> A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.

So, I have used it recently. It's so very nice, dude! But... I've got stuff to solve on it: **how do I use FTP/SFTP connection in active mode?** Yes, I have found no package able to do it. I have already tested these ones:

- remote-ftp (https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp)
- sftp-deployment (https://atom.io/packages/sftp-deployment)
- remote-edit (https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit)
- remote-sync (https://atom.io/packages/remote-sync)

Ideas? Tips? How-tos? Advices? Argues?

Comment: Why do you need to use active mode? Note that it's very difficult for [active mode FTP to work thought Windows firewall](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes#active) and any router/NAT you might use to connect to the internet.

Comment: Look, that's one server requirement for security reasons.

Comment: I've been searching for more options, too. Namely normal FTP (i.e. not SFTP) with TSL/SSL running in passive mode. I looked up the `secureOptions` in Node.js, too, but to no avail. The Coda editor may be the one you need. However, it is not free.

Comment: If you are using windows server and filezilla FTP Server, try setting the FTP server passive mode port to 50000-51000, and then add windows firewall inbound rule for that port range. Just work with the passive mode.